# Query to save to csv with counter

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your assistance. I am running the below sql query from Oracle SQL Developer so the results can be save to a csv file. I run this query using the Run Script and I can see the records that are being save to the csv file.

How can I modify the query so it can show me the number of records being save to the file? For example something like printing 1000 of 200000.

```
spool c:\temp\myoutputfile.csv
select * from mytable;
spool off;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add rownum column to your query result like below

```
select rownum, mytable.* from mytable;
```

Note, SQL doesn't have other options to print some text separately while  selection is under progress. Of course you have option to print some hard coded text as part of a resulted column. Otherwise you may have to write PL SQL procedure to meet your requirement.